libproc only showing one mapped region
I've got this MRE compiled on macOS:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <libproc.h>

int
main()
{
    int ret, num;
    struct proc_regionwithpathinfo info[20];

    ret = proc_pidinfo(getpid(), PROC_PIDREGIONPATHINFO, 0, &info, sizeof(info));
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("proc_pidinfo");
        return 1;
    }

    num = ret / sizeof(info[0]);
    for (int k = 0; k < num; k++) {
        struct proc_regionwithpathinfo *region = &info[k];

        printf("0x%016llx - 0x%016llx\n", region->prp_prinfo.pri_address,
               region->prp_prinfo.pri_address + region->prp_prinfo.pri_size);
        if (region->prp_vip.vip_path[0]) {
            printf("\tPath = %s\n", region->prp_vip.vip_path);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

Even though otool -L a.out shows that the binary is linked against libSystem.B.dylib, the program outputs only
0x0000000104260000 - 0x0000000104264000
    Path = /Users/user/Projects/foo/a.out

Why doesn't libproc show all of the memory regions?

Just a guess ... I've looked through some of the source and it appears that the sizeof should be for one instance. The low level code [AFAICT] only returns one instance per call. But, it does use the extra arg. Try looping: for (int k = 0; k < num; k++) { struct proc_regionwithpathinfo *region = &info[k]; ret = proc_pidinfo(getpid(), PROC_PIDREGIONPATHINFO, k, region, sizeof(*region)); if (ret < 0) { perror("proc_pidinfo"); return 1; } printf(...); }

@CraigEstey, no good.  It just keeps giving me the same region.
